# Email service without SSL authentication

Tags: email, authentication, ssl

Does anyone know an email service that doesn't require the SSL or TLS authentication to send mails throught smtp?

**Edit:** I don't know almost anythings about smtpm servers; the PC of my customer is really ancient and I cant install anything on it.

My hoster said that we can turn of for that domain the ssl auth for the IP auth, and should work, but obviously my customer doesn't have a static IP address for his connection.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want that?

Comment: Becose a costumer of mine have a software (old...) that doesnt allow the ssl auth.
The main email service is hosted by google apps, but it require ssl.
We tried to create another email account on our server (using plesk), but still require it.

Comment: @grawit: There's also other reasons. Some devices have the ability to send mail, like cameras or even a voice recorder I once owned. More often than not, they do not provide SSL ot TLS support. There may also be the need if you are creating certain web services on your website and wish to quickly send emails to the webmaster (that's you) when users fill in a form or to provide data on website usage.

Comment: @DaNiel, I see your edit. But the answers remain. Try your customer ISP smtp server. You should obtain this information for the ISP itself.

Comment: @Strae Were you trying to setup email settings for LabTech? I'm stuck at the same point in that case.

Comment: @pulsarjune nope, my customer has an ancient erp software to manage invoices, and that software was unable to use SSL or TLS. The email of his domain is under Google apps, so encryption is required; I solved creating a subdomain with a single send-only email address on the server with ip based auth (my customer has a static ip address)

Comment: @Strae thanks for the walk-thorugh. This might help me. I have researched and found that Lycos mail provides SSL-less email service. I have opted for that option. Fingers-crossed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing authentication details does not necessarily imply using encryption such as SSL.

So, if one cannot use the internet provider's SMTP server like A Dwarf suggested (which would actually do authentication based on the connection details, instead of login credentials), then entering some username and password without explicitely using SSL might still work very well.

(Note that *a few* SMTP servers only support username/password authentication when connecting through some specific port, like 587 aka [Submission Identification Port](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4409.txt), or even only on a specific domain like `authsmtp.example.com`. SSL by default uses port 465, *regardless* of any authentication.)

Some providers also support authentication using [POP before SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP).

Though you claim you cannot install *anything*: if you could install [DeleGate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/) then it might be configured as a [SMTP to SMTPS gateway](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/HowToDG.html#sslgateway) (a bit like the question [Force web address to go through https](https://superuser.com/questions/1501/force-web-address-to-go-through-https) here on Super User)... So, if all else fails: what OS are you on?

Comment: +1. Good answer Arjan. Do click those links DaNiel. This is the way to go if my suggestion fails. I'd say Arjan nails it better than I did.

Comment: ... **if** one cannot use the internet provider's SMTP server!

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP's SMTP (and even POP3) servers most probably doesn't require SSL or TLS encryption. Configure your device to those addresses and give it a shot.

Otherwise if this is being done on your computer you can also set your own SMTP server for mail forwarding. Programs like [Free SMTP Server](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html) or [PHP SMTP Server](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/E-mail-Servers/PHP-SMTP-Server-for-Windows.shtml) will allow you to do just that.

Comment: Shouldnt an email sent by those software being seen as spam, becose of the sender's ip?

Comment: @DaNieL: only if that service is on a blacklist like (see http://emailstuff.org/bl/), or if the sender's domain has SPF records defined (see http://www.openspf.org/Introduction)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the SMTP servers require SSL authen­ti­ca­tion.

Few Web­sites like the two listed below pro­vide you an option to dis­able SLL authen­ti­ca­tion. These sites allow you to use them as SMTP servers that does not require SSL authentication

To use them as a SMTP

- Sign up for an account on the website
- Note down the User name and Pass­word for the account

SMTP Server Set­tings for Lavabit.com

SMTP Server Address : lavabit.com
User name : xyz
Pass­word : *****

SMTP Server Set­tings for Inmail24.com

SMTP Server Address : (smtp/pop3).inmail24.com
User name : xyz@inmail24.com
Password : *****

Comment: Struggled to send mail from my embedded linux which has no ssl support, and then tried your suggestion - lavabit.com, worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Lavabit was effectively shut down by the US government for not providing backdoor encryption keys to user emails, so lavabit is no longer an option.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavabit

Answer (score 0):

You can use mail.bg. Enable smtp/pop/imap access from settings (settings->general->the first checkbox). Translate the web page with google translate it is in Bulgarian.

Answer (score 0):

smtp2go.com seem to have an option to authenticate without encryption. I use it with an old Samsung CLX-3170 scanner that has legacy firmware.