# force yahoo messenger to use https

Tags: internet-explorer, https, yahoo-messenger

I'm accessing yahoo messenger behind a firewall and it seems that yahoo messenger is blocked..

However i-tried the messenger via yahoo mail and it works if I use https.

I know IE is used by yahoo to establish connection, is there a way to force ie to use https when connecting with yahoo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can install NoScript plugins in FF and Chrome like browsers to support and force the use of https but in IE i dont think its possible..

Hey i got a link to force IE to use https connection for facebook..

Might be helpful for you...

[Force IE Https scripts](http://www.iescripts.org/view-scripts-880p1.htm)

which i got from this [post](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/31/how-to-force-https-connections/)

**Edit:**
See this link for a similar kind of question,
**[Force https in browser](https://superuser.com/questions/150632/force-a-browser-to-load-the-https-edition-of-a-website-not-the-http)**

Added a code sample below,

```
                    //==UserScript==
    //@name                    Facebook Secure Connection - Force Https (SSL)
    //@namespace               http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/86392
    //@namespace               http://www.maisdisdonc.com/
    //@description             Forces Facebook and all links in a Facebook page (include Notifications) to use a secure connection (https).
    //@version                 1.0.11
    //@date                    15:19 10/10/2010
    //@author                  Merimac
    //@include                 http*
    //@include                 http*://*.facebook.com/*
    //@license                 Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
    //@license                 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.fr
    //==/UserScript==

    function $(q, root, single) {
    if (root && typeof root == 'string') { root = $(root, null, true); }
    root = root || document;
    if (q[0]=='#') { return root.getElementById(q.substr(1)); }
    else if (q[0]=='/' || (q[0]=='.' && q[1]=='/')) {
       if (single) { return document.evaluate(q, root, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; }
       return document.evaluate(q, root, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    }
    else if (q[0]=='.') { return root.getElementsByClassName(q.substr(1)); }
    return root.getElementsByTagName(q);
    }

    function fnEnableFacebookHttps() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf("http://www.facebook.com")==0 ||
       url.indexOf("http://apps.facebook.com")==0) {
       window.location.replace(location.href.replace(url.substring(0,7), "https://"));
    }
    }

    function fnEnableHttpsLinks() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf("https://")==0) {
       for(var i=0,link; (link=document.links[i]); i++) {
           if(link.href.indexOf("http://")==0)
           link.href = link.href.replace(link.href.substring(0,7), "https://");
       }
    }
    }

    function fnEnableHttpsFacebookLinks(){
    var links = $("//a[contains(@href,'facebook.com')]");
    //alert(links.snapshotItem(1).href);
    for (var i=0; i<links.snapshotLength; i++) {
       links.snapshotItem(i).href = links.snapshotItem(i).href.replace(/^http:\/\/([^\.]*\.)?facebook\.com\/l\.php\?u\=http\%([^\.]*\.)/,'https://$1facebook.com/l.php?u=https%$2');
       links.snapshotItem(i).href = links.snapshotItem(i).href.replace(/^http:\/\/([^\.]*\.)?facebook\.com\//,'https://$1facebook.com/');
    }
    }


    document.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function() {
    fnEnableFacebookHttps(),
    fnEnableHttpsFacebookLinks(),
    setTimeout(function() { fnEnableHttpsFacebookLinks() }, 1000);
    },
```

Comment: yes i know but thats why i have mentioned Might be helpful for you

Comment: If you edit and update your question with the script I will remove my downvote.  I was the one who didn't read what the author was asking.

Comment: Thanks so much i've seen this ie script before, i just didnt care to  read it till now since it was just for facebook.  I think i can alter the script for yahoo messenger. thanks